# Accessing properties of input helpers on form

Tags: javascript, ember.js

i'm trying to create a new book in my database, but my layout is very different, i don't have a button submit in my form, he is outside, like:

```
<form>
 <label>Name</label>
 {{input value=book.name}}
</form>

<button>Create</button>
```

So.. i'm trying like this:

I'm returning a object in my `routes/books/new.js`:

```js
export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
  model () {
    return {
      name: 'test',
    };
  },

  setupController (controller, model) {
    controller.set('book', model);
  }
});
```

And in my button i have the action save. So, when someone clicks, in my `controller/books.js` i have:

```js
actions: {
 save () {
   console.log(this.get('book');
 }
}
```

And this is returning `undefined`.

Comment: Can you post the full code of `controller/books.js` ?

Comment: I already posted @RubensMariuzzo.. I just have this save action..

Comment: Don't you have anything else?

Comment: Nop.. that's my first time using Ember..

Comment: Ok, don't worry, I will be on my laptop in a few mins

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help @RubensMariuzzo

Comment: Hei @RubensMariuzzo, are you there?

Comment: Yes, I'm here now. Sorry. I will post my suggestion to try.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `controller/books.js` into an Ember's controller.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        save () {
            console.log(this.get('book')); 
                                     // ^ don't forget the parenthese here.
        }
    }
});
```

Give a try as is, and let me know in the comments.

Comment: Hei Rubins, i'm sorry.. when you ask if there was anything else, i was thinking that the default object was not include.. My code have the export default wrapping the action already...

Comment: I see. What version of Ember do you have?

Comment: If you want we can Hangouts or talk, check my email address on my Github profile.